# Securing Prometheus and end node communication

Tags: prometheus

I am looking to move to Prometheus from existing monitoring system. however would like to know if there is any option that we be sure that Prometheus can work on 443 https. Like i am not having much idea about Prometheus and wanted to know if we can make it work that what ever data is getting pulled from various systems by Prometheus be secure and encrypted if we have valid SSL cert. Any idea? As in docs i can see various exporters uses different different ports and Prometheus has pull method so not sure when the pulled data will be on internet how we can make it secure and encrypted.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus currently doesn't support authentication. The recommended approach for now is to setup a [reverse proxy with Nginx](https://www.robustperception.io/adding-basic-auth-to-prometheus-with-nginx/) or Apache.

Comment: The question is about scraping the node exporter over https, not about basic auth